# Powershell script can't find URL

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a `powershell` that kicks off a `workflow` in `SharePoint` but my system is not allowing me to run it. The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Get-SPWeb: Cannot find an SPWeb object with id or URL: xxx.com and site Url xxx.com
At C:\cert.ps1:1 char:17
+ $web = Get-SPWeb <<<< -Identity "xxx.com"
  + CategoryInfo  : InvalidData (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletGetWeb:SPCmdletGetWeb) [Get-SPWeb], SPCmdletPipeBindException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.SPCmdletGetWeb
```

I tried adding `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell` but I the get an error saying its already been added.

Here's the script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "xxx.com" 
$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager   
$list = $web.Lists["Certificate Tracking"]

$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Certificate Notification","en-US")

$view = $list.Views["All Items"] #All Items
$items = $list.GetItems($view)  

$data = $assoc.AssociationData

foreach ($item in $items) {
 $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data) 
}

$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-Identity` parameter for `Get-SPWeb` can be either a full or relative path, or a path with a wildcard `*` character.  Additionally:

```
The identity param expects a valid URL in the form http://server_name or a relative path in the form of /SubSites/MySubSite.
```

Try this instead using the -Site param, which I think might be what you're looking for:

```
Get-SPWeb -Site http://sitename/sites/site1
```

Comment: I hate Microsoft...I changed it to `Site` and it got rid of the error but couldn't initialize the variables. I changed it back to `Identity` and it worked. Go figure